# Where can I get a splitter to connect a device with a single 3.5 mm plug into the audio input/output jacks on my laptop?

Tags: laptop, microphone, audio-output

I recently bought the :Hype Retro Handset for Mobile Phone" -- its just a device that looks like a handset to use when chatting on a computer or mobile phone that plugs into the phone/computer with a single 3.5 mm plug.  I was hoping to use it on my windows 7 Toshiba laptop.  I can hear audio fine through the handset but what I'm saying is not being picked up on the handset.

On the box it says "some phones and computers may need additional adapters," so I'm hoping it is possible to get a splitter or something for this to work properly.  I did email the parent company (http://dglusa.com/) but I haven't heard from them, and, looking over their website, I doubt I will.  I also went to the local radio shack, and the guy said I needed a splitter, but he didn't know where to get one.

I can find the kind of splitter I think I need online, but I'm unsure whether they are just for output or can also do input/output.

Answer (score 1):

You can purchase an adapter at Radio Shack, Amazon, and likely many other places. This [Google search](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=3.5mm%20mic%20headset%20splitter&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=&pbx=1&fp=87c6230bd8e448f1&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&biw=1326&bih=815) offers up many examples of the correct product that you can buy from a variety of locations. Please note that you want the choices from that list that have **one hole, and two jacks**; not the choices that have one jack with two holes.

Answer (score 1):

You need an adapter to plug into the microphone jack and the audio output jack on the PC and convert that to the single 3.5mm plug you have.  This combines the audio and microphone into a single 3.5mm jack.  This is an unusual adapter but I am sure they must exist.  As USB audio is more common, the device you need is less common.  This init would work.  Not sure availability in your location [Startech adapter](http://ca.startech.com/Cables/Audio-Video/Audio-Cables/35mm-4-Position-to-2x-3-Position-35mm-Headset-Splitter-Adapter-F-M~MUYHSFMM)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the plug on the phone and count the rings.  If there is a tip, two rings, and the "sleeve" then it's an iPhone style connector -- stereo headphone plus mike.  If there is only one ring then it's a standard "stereo" connector with the headphone connected on one side and the mike on the other.

The first type would need a special splitter you can probably only find on the web.  For the second type you can use a "stereo to mono splitter" or some such that splits the "stereo" signal into two "mono" signals -- one will be the headphone, the other the mike.  (You will have to experiment to see which side is the headphone and which the mike.)